# Import and transform json file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a json file and I uploaded with the following way:

```
# Import libraries 
import json
import pandas as pd

# Load the data 
with open('data.json') as user_file:
  file_contents = user_file.read()
```

The output looks like

```
print(file_contents)
>> {"id": 0, "text": "Nicklikes football"}
{"id": 1, "George likes basketball"}
{"id": 2, "text": "John likes swimming"}
```

**Is there any way to create a dataframe with the first column the IDs and the other column the text?**

I have tried the following but it's not working

```
texts = [{'Id': file_contents[k][i]['id'], 'Text': file_contents[k][i]['text']} for k in file_contents for i in range(len(file_contents[k]))]
dt = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(texts)
```

Comment: Your print looks weird, should the second line be: `{"id": 1, "text": "George likes basketball"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for `pandas`'s `read_json()` [1].

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("data.json", orient="records")
```

`orient` must fit the format of the JSON file. I believe your file is record-like:

```json
[
    {"id": 0, "text": "Nicklikes football"},
    {"id": 1, "text": "George likes basketball"},
    {"id": 2, "text": "John likes swimming"}
]
```

If not and you have individual JSON structures per line, use

```py
df = pd.read_json("data.json", lines=True)
```

[1] https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually I used this one and it's working 'df = pd.read_json('data.json', lines=True)'